# How do I make DOMContentLoaded select all specific div elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a project where visitors will need to access small pop-up windows to access the content. But it is only once a day.

I already managed to be part of the script but this jQuery only selects the first div element. How do I select all of the specific div elements?

http://jsfiddle.net/bieldade/r8Lo370y/70/

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var vlz = document.getElementById("vlz");
  var ls = localStorage.getItem("vlz");
  var data = new Date();
  var data_atual = data.valueOf();
  var data24 = data.setSeconds(data.getSeconds() + 5);

  if (ls < data_atual) {
    vlz.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("clz").onclick = function() {
      localStorage.setItem("vlz", data24);
      vlz.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.select {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px
}

#vlz {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="vlz" class='select'>
  <div class='vlz-shw'>
    show
  </div>
  <div id="clz" class='select'>cose</div>
</div>

<div id="vlz" class='select'>
  <div class='vlz-shw'>
    show
  </div>
  <div id="clz" class='select'>cose</div>
</div>

<div id="vlz" class='select'>
  <div class='vlz-shw'>
    show
  </div>
  <div id="clz" class='select'>cose</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You use the same ids multiple times, but ids have to be unique. Better use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have multiple `div`'s with same id, you can use `class` instead.
There are newer ways to select elements in javascript with `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.

When you select elements with the class selector, you need to loop through them and add an event listener individually.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bieldade/r8Lo370y/70/)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var vlz = document.querySelectorAll(".vlz");
  var ls = localStorage.getItem("vlz");
  var data = new Date();
  var data_atual = data.valueOf();
  var data24 = data.setSeconds(data.getSeconds() + 5);

  if (ls < data_atual) {
    vlz.forEach(v => {
      v.classList.add('showvlz')
    })
  }

  document.querySelectorAll(".clz").forEach(c => {
    c.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      // do stuff here
        event.target.parentNode.classList.add('removevlz');
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.select {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px
}

.vlz {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #555;
}

.showvlz {
  display: block;
}

.removevlz {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="vlz" class='select'>
  <div class='vlz-shw'>
    show
  </div>
  <div class="clz" class='select'>cose</div>
</div>

<div class="vlz" class='select'>
  <div class='vlz-shw'>
    show
  </div>
  <div class="clz" class='select'>cose</div>
</div>

<div class="vlz" class='select'>
  <div class='vlz-shw'>
    show
  </div>
  <div class="clz" class='select'>cose</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the 'localStorage.setItem("vlz", data24);' to appear the option to view the content only in 24. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should use classes instead of ids. I suggest you to use **querySelectorAll** once you changed *id* to *class*

`document.querySelectorAll('.vlz')`